# On the Bounded Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Question:** Does the Bounded Convergence Theorem hold if $\operatorname{m}\left(E\right)<+\infty$ but we drop the assumption that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $E$ but still pointwise bounded?

I know that the answer is no, however, I cannot think of a counterexample. I though about the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$f_n(x):=n\cdot\chi_{(0,1/n[}.$$

But this sequence is not pointwise bounded.

---

For reference, this is a modification of a question out of Roydens Real Analysis text. Moreover, the question out of Roydens Real Analysis text is the following:

**Question:** Does the Bounded Convergence Theorem hold if $\operatorname{m}\left(E\right)<+\infty$ but we drop the assumption that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $E$?

Obviously, the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ defined above suffices as a counterexample for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $(0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure as follows:
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x) = x^{-1} \chi_{[n^{-2},n^{-1}]}(x)
\end{align*}
We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n} = 0$ pointwise in $(0,1]$.  Further, $f_{n}(x) \leq x^{-1}$ so we are pointwise bounded.  However, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) \, dx \neq 0$ as
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) \, dx = \int_{n^{-2}}^{n^{-1}} x^{-1} \, dx = \log(n^{-1}) - \log(n^{-2}) = \log(n).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Could you explain the last inequality?

Comment: Yes, the explanation is it was an error!  I edited the answer.

Comment: Just now seeing this, but this is a great answer! Thanks.